# Using Session IDs instead of JWT for Authentication in Next-Auth

Tags: authentication, session, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I hope you're all doing well. I am currently working with Next-Auth in a Next.js project, and I have a question regarding authentication using Session IDs instead of JWT.

In my authentication setup, I am currently using JWT for session authentication, but I want to explore the possibility of using Session IDs.

Below is a snippet of my current Next-Auth configuration:

> ```
> providers: [
>   CredentialsProvider({
>     name: "credentials",
>     credentials: {
>       // my credentials
>     },
>
>     // authorize function
>     async authorize(credentials, request) {
>       const response = await fetch("api url", {
>         method: "POST",
>         headers: {
>           "Content-type": "application/json",
>         },
>         body: JSON.stringify({
>           // my credentials
>         }),
>       });
>
>       // await user
>       const data = await response.json();
>       const user = data.user
>
>       // error handling
>       if (user && response.ok) {
>         return user;
>       }
>       
>       return null;
>     },
>   }),
> ],
>
> pages: { signIn: "/entrar" },
>
> callbacks: {
>   // json web token
>   async jwt({ token, user }) {
>     if (user) token.user = user;
>     return token;
>   },
>
>   // session (is logged in)
>   async session({ session, token }) {
>     session = token.user as Session;
>     return session;
>   },
> },
> // ... (existing code)
> ```

I would like to know how I can modify this setup to use Session IDs instead of JWT for authentication. If anyone has experience with this or can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

I was also wondering if JWT isn't already Session ID, but as far as I know it isn't, so I should really approach it differently. If I'm wrong, please explain to me.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!